# Actualizar la vista del componente hijo, cuando cambien los valores del padre. Angular

Tags: angular, angular5

Tengo un componente padre que recupera datos de un servicio al que tengo que estar llamando cada X tiempo. Esto lo hago con un setInterval

Este componente padre pasa mediante `@Input` varios parametros a un componente hijo que es el que despliega la vista. Necesito que cada vez que se actualicen los datos (al recibir datos del servicio) en el componente padre, refresque la vista del hijo para que se reflejen en el.

Componente padre:

```
ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(this.getData(), 5000);
  }

  getData(): void {
    this.allData = this.zoneService.getDatas();
  }
```

html:

```
<app-place *ngIf="allData" [distancia]="allData?.metros"
  [texto]="allData?.message"
  [zona]="allData?.zoneSelected?.id"></app-place>
```

Componente hijo:

```
export class PlaceComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() distancia: number;
  @Input() zona: number;
  @Input() texto: string;
```

Comment: En principio tal como lo tienes debería funcionar: cualquier cambio en los valores marcados con `@Input()` provocan un refresco en la vista

Comment: Yo también lo veo bien. ¿Cuál es el problema que te da? Porque entiendo que en el PlaceComponent estás renderizando los Input {{ distancia }}, {{ zona }} y {{ texto }}

Comment: Pues al final, la cosa más tonta. El error lejos de estar en dónde yo creía radicaba simplemente en una mala construcción del set Interval. setInterval(() => {this.getData() }, 5000);